# How do weekends/holidays affect deadlines for past years?

Tags: united-states, taxes

What happens with weekends and holidays and *amended* tax deadlines?  Take for instance a 2014 amendment.

2014 taxes were due on April 15, 2015.

The statute of limitations for amending taxes is 3 years past the due date.  3 years would be April 15, 2018.

However, April 15, 2018 is a Sunday.

Even more, April 16, 2018 is Emancipation Day, the District of Columbia's holiday *that's completely unrelated to taxes* (seriously, that's when Lincoln signed the Emancipation Proclamation.  In DC.)  That makes the deadline for 2017 taxes April 17, 2018.

**What do these weekends and holidays do**, if anything, **to** the "statute of limitations" **deadlines for filing or amending past years** (2014 in this example)?

Answer (score 3):

The [IRS site](https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/time-is-running-out-to-file-2014-tax-returns-worth-1-billion-in-refunds) states the last chance to claim a refund for a 2014 tax return is April 17, 2018.

This seems consistent for prior years, rather than being 3-years exactly, it's the current year tax deadline.

Last chance for [2014](https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/time-is-running-out-to-file-2014-tax-returns-worth-1-billion-in-refunds) - Tuesday, April 17, 2018
  -  Original 2014 tax deadline was Wednesday, April 15, 2015
Last chance for [2013](https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/time-running-out-to-claim-1-billion-in-tax-refunds-from-2013) - Tuesday, April 18, 2017
 - Original 2013 tax deadline was Tuesday, April 15, 2014
Last chance for [2012](https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/time-running-out-to-claim-950-million-in-refunds-for-2012-tax-returns) - Monday, April 18, 2016
 - Original 2012 tax deadline was Monday, April 15, 2013

Those are the only years I see on IRS site. Those all work to benefit the late-filer, so tried to find a year when the original tax deadline was later than the 15th. In 2006 the original deadline was April 17th, 2007, according to [RapidTax.com](https://www.rapidtax.com/blog/april-15-deadline-to-receive-refund-for-2006-late-filers/) Thursday, April 15, 2010 was the last chance to claim a 2006 refund. I suspect that site is correct and that the IRS doesn't want to fuss with multiple due dates, so people get 3-years +/- a couple days.

Comment: I wonder, since 3 years after the 2017 deadline (April 17, 2018) is a Saturday, should the last date to amend a 2017 return be the next business day--Monday, April 19, 2021? Or will it be Thursday, April 15, 2021?

Comment: @prl I wondered the same, updated with some findings, but no IRS to confirm it's sometimes less than 3-years.